# "Save Image As" fails for certain Google search image previews, using Firefox

Tags: firefox, downloads

In a Google image search, I am unable to save certain images via the preview, while others I can save from the preview.

For the ones that don't save, when I right-click the preview and select *Save Image As*, I can select the destination folder and click *Save*, yet the image doesn't save and the download is marked as failed in my Firefox browser. I have to click *Retry Download* to save these images. If I directly view the images I save all of them successfully the first time.

#### Examples:

(note that they are similar in size):

- [This does not save.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sega+master+system+poster&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7ovyO36_eAhUFwVkKHWDcDT0Q_AUIDigB&biw=1280&bih=924#imgdii=tWhcivPaVaBOmM:&imgrc=Y3I-ZBFmcG09HM:)
- [This does save.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sega+master+system+poster&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7ovyO36_eAhUFwVkKHWDcDT0Q_AUIDigB&biw=1280&bih=924#imgrc=Y3I-ZBFmcG09HM:)

This started happening today, and again, only for certain image previews. I tried a different computer with an out of date Ubuntu installed and all images save normally there, so it might be specific to my system.

Answer (score 7):

This issue is completely reproducible. The first link links to a Sega Master System webpage containing a poster image. The second link links to a gallery page at https://imgur.com/ image hosting website. Firefox is able to automatically find the link to the second image on imgur and download it. Firefox can also automatically find and download images from gallery pages at Flickr and Pinterest image hosting websites, but it can't do the same thing if the image is embedded on many other webpages.

To save this image, right-click the image and from the pop-up context menu select *View Image*. Then right-click the image obtained by View Image and select *Save Image As...* to save the image. This will save a huge image with tiny writing on it which is clearly readable in the saved image.

Comment: I suspected that the image was too large, but the other one that saves successfully from the preview is almost the same size. The problem also happens on selected smaller images. It seems more like the link chain to the actual image may be a factor.

Comment: I'm not really following the cause/rationale here, and it works perfectly in Safari. If you have an image you should be able to right-click download it, period. Why does Firefox need to "find" it again and why does this not succeed when it previously did?